# A RenderFlex overflowed by 399 pixels on the right in flutter appbar

Tags: flutter, icons

I want to add an icon to the appBar of my flutter app but I get this error:

**A RenderFlex overflowed by 399 pixels on the right.**

I used AppIcon.com to create the different versions of the icon and AppIcon.com put the icons in the mipmap folder. I then copied those folders into my Flutter project.

Then, I copied the smallest version which is 72x72 to the directory where I point the appBar code to. Here is the appBar code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // removes the back button in appbar
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Image.asset('lib/assets/images/dd_logo_building.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          const Text(' Deal Diligence'),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () {
            signOut();
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the entire error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 399 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Row Row:file:///C:/deal_diligence/deal_diligence/lib/screens/widgets/my_appbar.dart:29:14

To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
http://127.0.0.1:9100/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A53395%2Fg2EuruVAEB8%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-7

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#317c3 relayoutBoundary=up14 OVERFLOWING:
  creator: Row ← _AppBarTitleBox ← Semantics ← DefaultTextStyle ← MediaQuery ←
    LayoutId-[<_ToolbarSlot.middle>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← NavigationToolbar ← DefaultTextStyle ←
    IconTheme ← Builder ← CustomSingleChildLayout ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=312.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(312.7, 54.0)
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 1519 libraries in 3,684ms (compile: 1922 ms, reload: 352 ms, reassemble: 703 ms).
D/EGL_emulation( 7691): app_time_stats: avg=1490.61ms min=1490.61ms max=1490.61ms count=1
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "lib/assets/images/dd_logo_building.png".
```

I have an older icon that is 72x72 that works so why won't this icon work or how do I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid an overflow, just wrap the `Image.asset` with a [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget:

```dart
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flexible( // <-- add this
              child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/dd_logo_building.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
            ),
            const Text(' Deal Diligence'),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this if you want a more space in your appbar.**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      flexibleSpace: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'lib/assets/images/dd_logo_building.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 56,
          ),
          const Text(' Deal Diligence'),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () {
            signOut();
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expanded` and `Flexible` Widgets to get rid of Overflow issue

`Expanded Widget:`

The Expanded widget makes a child of a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` expand to fill the available space along the main axis (horizontally for Row, vertically for Column).

It's a shorthand for Flexible with a flex factor of 1 and a fit of `FlexFit.tight`. This means it forces the child to fill the available space.
When multiple Expanded widgets are used within a `Row` or `Column`, the available space is divided among them according to their flex factors.

`Flexible Widget:`

The Flexible widget allows for more nuanced control over how a child is sized within a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex`.

It has two key properties: flex and fit. The flex property is a flex factor that determines how much of the remaining space in the layout the child will occupy, relative to other Flexible children.

The fit property determines how the child is forced to fit into the allocated space, with options being `FlexFit.tight` (forces child to fill the space) and `FlexFit.loose` (child can be smaller than the available space).

`Flexible` with a fit of `FlexFit.loose` allows its child to have a maximum size up to the allocated space but doesn't force it to fill all of it, which is different from `Expanded`.